# Sonata Media - Custom Download strategy

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I have an Entity named "Document" and I use sonata media to handle the file management. So, an Admin can add a new document and attach a file, this document is assigned to an user.

My problem is :
I want the users to be able to download the files that are assigned to them through the "Protected URL"(because if you change the number at the end of the download url, you are able to download files that are assigned to other users)

According to the Sonata Media's doc, I need to create a Download Strategy and the service. I did it, i called it : PrivateDownloadStrategy.php (and made the service)
This file should be based on RolesDownloadStrategy.php, because i want the admins able to download all the files, but how to do for the users be able to download the files that are assigned to them ?

This is my actual PrivateDownloadStrategy.php (copy from rolesDownloadStrategy.php)

```
<?php
namespace Application\Core\DocumentBundle\Security;

use Sonata\MediaBundle\Security\DownloadStrategyInterface;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\MediaInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class PrivateDownloadStrategy implements DownloadStrategyInterface
{
    protected $roles;

    protected $security;

    protected $translator;

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface        $translator
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface $security
     * @param array                                                     $roles
     */
    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator, SecurityContextInterface $security, array $roles = array())
    {
        $this->roles      = $roles;
        $this->security   = $security;
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\MediaInterface  $media
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isGranted(MediaInterface $media, Request $request)
    {
        return $this->security->getToken() && $this->security->isGranted($this->roles);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->translator->trans('description.roles_download_strategy', array('%roles%' => '<code>'.implode('</code>, <code>', $this->roles).'</code>'), 'SonataMediaBundle');
    }
}
```

and the service :

```
<service id="sonata.media.security.private_strategy" class="Application\Core\DocumentBundle\Security\PrivateDownloadStrategy" >
            <argument type="service" id="translator" />
            <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
            <argument type="collection">
                <argument>ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN</argument>
                <argument>ROLE_ADMIN</argument>
            </argument>
        </service>
```

nb : sonata media doc : [link](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/security.html)
     sonata rolesDownloadStrategy : [link](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Security/RolesDownloadStrategy.php)

Comment: can you update your question with config for this service. and your PrivateDownloadStrategy.php file content?

Comment: I did copy-paste the one from sonata admin rolesDownloadStrategy. But i will edit my post

Comment: so, if everything is working fine, - you should just check for user in `isGranted` method;

Comment: I agree about using `isGranted` method, but I don't really know what code should I write. Do i need to get the download(media) id, then make a query and check what document has attached the media, and then check what user is related, and compare the user to the actual logged user, andif it is equal ? Sounds too much, because thats some new queries, and I don't know if I can use the queries that were done in the controller to display the page (and so, the download link).

Comment: in ```isGranted``` method already passed ```media``` object. So I think the best way will be to implement method canAccess($user) for media object, - and check current user from security context inside media;

Comment: but inside the media object, I can't retrieve to who the media is assigned, no ? Because it is inside the document entity where I define to who the media is assigned. (Maybe I am wrong)

Comment: you always can extend MediaObject and add there any additional methods you'd like. I.e. ```function assignedToUser($user) { return ... }```